# Expected value of a random variable and its square root

Tags: probability-distributions

Can the expectation of a random variable be written in this fashion: $$E(\sqrt{X} + X) = E(\sqrt{X}) + E(X)$$
Thanks in advance

Comment: Expectation is linear and hence for any random variables $X, Y$ and real constants $a, b$:

$$E[aX + bY] = aE[X] + bE[Y]$$

Comment: I suppose you are saying yes!